# Easiest way to authenticate users in Linux/Unix w/o root permissions

Tags: linux, unix, authentication

I'm writing a cross-platform TCP/IP server and I need to authenticate users before servicing them. Requirements stipulate that I use "native" authentication of the platform and not create my own authentication mechanism.

For Linux/Unix OS family I use getpwnam to authenticate users and the most reliable way I know to make sure this works is to start my service as root. There're no other reasons for the service to run as root and I wonder what my options are? Can I call getpwnam while not being root w/o compromising security? Or, if there're alternatives to getpwnam, how portable are they and how "administrator-friendly" in a sense of "what configuration effort they require? The reason why independent authentication mechanism is off the table is exactly that it creates "too much a configuration effort".

Comment: Why is it a security problem to use getpwnam not as root?

Comment: getpwnam only returns the user's actual password data if you're root.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [PAM authentication?](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/understandingpam.html)

Comment: From what I remember, PAM has restrictions for programs that change their user while running.  This is why, for instance, Apache can't access PAM from its child processes.

Comment: My application would have to be PAM aware. How much will it benefit admins? PAM is usually not installed by default as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer), for example [Cyrus SASL](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/downloads.html#sasl). No root privileges required and all popular Linux distributions support it. I'm using it to authenticate users of intranet site served by Apache and written in Python. Among others Sendmail and Postfix use it for authentication.

Comment: +1. If you want to use PAM (or shadow directly) with this method you'll need to use the plain mechanism. As the name infers, this means you'll have passwords coming in unencrypted which is no good. You'll need to provide your own encryption on the connection to keep the passwords out of the enemy's hands.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getpwnam()` does not require root privileges.

Trying to get information from the shadow password file, or AFAIK using PAM, does require root privileges, and that presents some problems.  However, you might be able to start your process as root, initialize access to PAM, and then drop privileges.  That is unconfirmed speculation, but is at least somewhat plausible.

Note that in most systems, `getpwnam()` does not return you an encrypted (or hashed) password.  So, you need to consider carefully what you are planning to do to 'authenticate' the user.

Comment: Yes, I also check getspnam result out before giving up authenticating the user. Was reasonably successful on Linux distros and Solaris so far.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 'root for PAM' bit.  I've seen some problems where it appeared that root privilege was needed, but my test example isn't working as either root or non-root (but with different errors, neither of them very helpful).  More investigation soon - I hope.